# How to use this custom CLSID from Internet Explorer in C++?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation

There is a Internet Explorer CLSID defined in registry which points to the IE executable.

I want to use this CLSID with CoCreateInstance function but cannot figure out to which library should I link this code.

I have added following to my code to my CPP -

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium;
ifdef __cplusplus
class DECLSPEC_UUID("D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E")
InternetExplorerMedium;
endif

hResult = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium,
    NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER,
    IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **) &m_pMyIE);
```

Since I could not figure out any header file having this CLSID, I have added this to my .CPP file also I could not figure out the type library.

Comment: so what errors are you getting when compiling? Or what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Since the declaration is 'EXTERN_C', linking fails for me

Comment: This CLSID is defined in the new version of PLatformSDK 7.1 and onwards in Exdisp.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using platform SDK solved the problem. Thank you, nyarlathotep